# Single API for various Databases in Python

Tags: python, database, api, perl

I hold good experience in working with Perl DBI module.The DBI module acts as single API for multiple databases like Oracle, Postgres, etc.

I have recently started working on Python and I noticed that there are separate API for each databases in Python.

Following are my questions:
1. Isn't there **single DB API** in Python?
2. If not, isn't this a disadvantage in Python?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, but you could use an ORM.

Answer (score 4):

There is no Python equivalent to Perl's DBI-centric ecosystem. Instead:

- The DBAPI (PEP 249) defines a common low-level interface that relational database drivers are expected to provide.
- Some projects like SQLAlchemy Core abstract over multiple drivers, using the common DBAPI interface.

Python's lack of a proper DBI equivalent is less of a disadvantage than it would be in Perl due to the different module system. Assuming you are restricting yourself to a common SQL subset and to the DBAPI instead of using driver-specific extensions, switching to a different driver can be as simple as changing an import, and updating the connection information:

```
- import somedatabase as db
+ import differentdriver as db
```

In practice, neither Python's DBAPI nor Perl's DBI will enable you to switch databases at a whim. However, Perl's DBI makes it much easier to write software that works with multiple databases.